# Array Max Consecutive Sum

Tags: javascript

Рядом порядка k,  массива A  мы назавем произвольно выбранную группу последовательных элементов,  количеством   k  из  позиции i.
Например для массива A = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]  порядка k = 2 ряды будут A = [2, 3]  A = [3, 5]  A = [5, 1]  A = [1, 6]  подмассивы.
Надо написать функцию, которая получает массив [x1, x2, x3, … xn] и возвращает максимальную сумму рядов порядка n.
Например в вышеуказанном примере мы получим 8, потому что оно наибольшое значение, которое получается когда мы слогаем элементы рядов. В нашом примере из ряда [3, 5].

```
function arrayMaxConsecutiveSum (input, k) {
    let sum = 0;
    let max = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        sum += input[i];
        if (i >= k) sum -= input[i - k];
        if (sum > max) max = sum;
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(solution([2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2], 2));    // 8
console.log(solution([2,4, 10, 1, 2], 2));       // 14
console.log(solution([2, 4, 10, 9, 2], 2));      // 19
console.log(solution([1, 3, 2, 4, 3], 3));       // 9
console.log(solution([5,4,1,3,2,4,3], 3));       // 10


А нужнно чтобы выводил. 

console.log(solution([2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2]));    // 8
console.log(solution([2,4, 10, 1, 2]));       // 14
console.log(solution([2, 4, 10, 9, 2]));      // 19
console.log(solution([1, 3, 2, 4, 3]));       // 9
console.log(solution([5,4,1,3,2,4,3]));       // 10

Заранее скажу что код проверяет спрогромированная 
система в котором уже есть тести которые проверяют все случая например для    
k =2, 3
```

Comment: Откуда в функции будет известно, какое k должно использоваться?

Comment: Это система вроде codewars. Оно внутри себя уже автоматически это проверяет просто не получается правильно вставить условия (например для k = 2, k = 3, ...) чтобы например в сучае console.log(arrayMaxConsecutiveSum([2,3,5,1,6,2]) выводил 8 и т,д.

Comment: Да почему 8 должно выводить?

Comment: Игорь это спрогромированная система в котором уже есть тести которые проверяют все случая например для k =2, 3 ...
Я это не пишу для простово броузера...

Comment: С  логической стороны вы правы да функция сам не может решить что выбрать 8 или 19



Я там указал все 5 тести просто не получается ставить условия для некоторых случиев k (k = 2, 3 ...)

Comment: if (input.join() == '2,3,5,1,6,2'){return 8;}

Comment: Я, кажется, начинаю догадываться, чего Вы хотите. Похоже, что нужна сумма, дающая максимальное среднее сложенных элементов.

Comment: Приведите подлинное условие, а не свою интерпретацию

Comment: Да ладно я свою интерпретацию сейчас уадлью подлинние условия вверху, до кода

Comment: Дайте ссылку на задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Я не понял, почему функция должна вывести `8`, когда нет второгo параметра.

```js
function solution(inp, k) {
  let sum = 0;
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++)
    max += inp[i];
  sum = max;

  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length - k; i++) {
    sum = sum - inp[i] + inp[i + k];
    if (sum > max) 
      max = sum;
  }
  
  return max;
}

console.log(solution([2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2], 2));    // 8
console.log(solution([2,4, 10, 1, 2], 2));       // 14
console.log(solution([2, 4, 10, 9, 2], 2));      // 19
console.log(solution([1, 3, 2, 4, 3], 3));       // 9
```

Похоже, что нужна сумма, дающая максимальное среднее сложенных элементов.

```js
function solution(inp, k) {
  let sum = 0;
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++)
    max += inp[i];
  sum = max;

  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length - k; i++) {
    sum = sum - inp[i] + inp[i + k];
    if (sum > max) 
      max = sum;
  }
  
  return max;
}

function solutionMaxAvg(inp) {
  let sum, avg;
  let max, maxAvg;
  for (let i = 2; i <= inp.length; i++) {
    sum = solution(inp, i);
    avg = sum / i;
    if (i == 2 || avg > maxAvg) {
      max = sum;
      maxAvg = avg
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(solutionMaxAvg([2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2]));
console.log(solutionMaxAvg([2,4, 10, 1, 2]));
console.log(solutionMaxAvg([2, 4, 10, 9, 2]));
console.log(solutionMaxAvg([1, 3, 2, 4, 3]));
console.log(solutionMaxAvg([5,4,1,3,2,4,3]));
```

Comment: Функция должна вывести 8 потому что по требованию задачи функция получает только массив...

Comment: @Stilius Почему 8, а не 19?

Comment: потому что 19 это сумма всех элементов в случае [2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2]

Comment: @Stilius Вы идиот? Как функция должна понять, что она должна складывать по два элемента массива?

Comment: Идиот это вы. Нельзя так разговоривать.

Comment: @Stilius Хорошо. Не буду.